# PHP PDO foreach or while in slider?

Tags: mysql, pdo, foreach, while-loop, slider

I have the following code:

I'm trying to mix a jquery slider, with some php and mysql to retrieve the slider images from a database and all its info.

It connects sucessfully but I could only retrieve just 1 row, from the results and I need to retrieve at least 6 rows... I can't just duplicate the number of slides no matter what. Yes, I've tested the slider with local values and it works perfect

I'll be appreciated for any help here.

PD: One of my errors, could be bad formatted HTML, after  tag

```
  <body>
   <?php
   function getContent() {
    try {
       $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=xx', 'xx', 'xx');
       $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         die();
     }
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM homeslider ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
     $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
     $query->execute();
     $row = $query->fetchAll();
     return $row;
   }
   ?>

    <div id="wrapper">
         <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="Slider">
                <?php 
             $data = getContent();  
             foreach ($data as $row) {
             $id = $row['id'];
             $titulo = $row['titulo'];
             $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
             $link = $row['link'];
             $imgurl = $row['imgurl'];
             $ultimo_update = $row['ultimo_update'];    
                }   

                echo'
                <a href="#1"><img src="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-thumb="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-transition="fold" title="#htmlcaption_'.$id.'" /></a>
            </div> <!-- Cierra slider -->
            <div id="htmlcaption_'.$id.'" class="nivo-html-caption">
               '.$titulo.'<br/>'.$descripcion.'<span class="sliderButtonSpan"><a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;">Leer más <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a></span>
            </div> <!-- Cierra htmlcaption_# -->
            </div> <!-- Cierra slider-wrapper -->
         </div> <!-- Cierra wrapper -->
         ';?>
         <div style="text-align:center;font-size:2em;">SK-Servicios.com</div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.slider.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(window).load(function() {

             $('#slider').Slider({  
         });

         });

      </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: a var dump of data? a var dump inside the function after the fetch?

Comment: WHY ALL CAPS IN TITLE?

Comment: Move the echo statement inside your foreach loop

Comment: how can i do that? it giving me headaches!! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Move the echo statement inside the foreach() loop

```
   <?php 
$data = getContent();  
foreach ($data as $row) {
 echo '<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div id="slider" class="Slider">';
   $id = $row['id'];
   $titulo = $row['titulo'];
   $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
   $link = $row['link'];
   $imgurl = $row['imgurl'];
   $ultimo_update = $row['ultimo_update'];    
 }   

 echo'
 <a href="#1"><img src="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-thumb="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-transition="fold" title="#htmlcaption_'.$id.'" /></a>
</div> <!-- Cierra slider -->
<div id="htmlcaption_'.$id.'" class="nivo-html-caption">
 '.$titulo.'<br/>'.$descripcion.'<span class="sliderButtonSpan"><a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;">Leer más <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a></span>
</div> <!-- Cierra htmlcaption_# -->
</div> <!-- Cierra slider-wrapper -->
</div> <!-- Cierra wrapper -->
';?>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your interest to help me, it worked partially, as last favor, what could i've done wrong here? It looks like this  http://prntscr.com/5iingl THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, its looking much better now, the only problem is... http://prntscr.com/5iisht

THANK you, really, im appreciated!

Comment: I cant see the problem, are you using a layout frame work e.g. Bootstrap, JQueryUI?

Comment: Hello, im using bootstrap 3.2.0 and jquery 1.9.0 loaded in that order.

Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

change your loop like this

```
<?php 
 $data = getContent();  
         foreach ($data as $row) {
         echo '<div id="wrapper">
         <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
         <div id="slider" class="Slider">';
         $id = $row['id'];
         $titulo = $row['titulo'];
         $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
         $link = $row['link'];
         $imgurl = $row['imgurl'];
         $ultimo_update = $row['ultimo_update'];                     
            echo'
            <a href="#1"><img src="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-thumb="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-transition="fold" title="#htmlcaption_'.$id.'" /></a>
        </div> <!-- Cierra slider -->
        <div id="htmlcaption_'.$id.'" class="nivo-html-caption">
           '.$titulo.'<br/>'.$descripcion.'<span class="sliderButtonSpan"><a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;">Leer más <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a></span>
        </div> <!-- Cierra htmlcaption_# -->
        </div> <!-- Cierra slider-wrapper -->
     </div> <!-- Cierra wrapper -->
     ';
     }

?>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your interest to help me, it worked partially, as last favor, what could i've done wrong here? It looks like this  http://prntscr.com/5iingl THANK YOU!!!